# symfony 3.4 FirewallListener Slow / Blocking

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

When i´m doing a request to a "huge" page with a lot of data to load, and make a second request to a "normal" content page, the normal page is blocked until the "huge" is loaded.

I activated the Profiler and recognized that the FirewallListener was the blocking element).

Profiler Screenshots (Loaded huge, switched tab - loaded normal)
**Huge**
[image: Huge Page Load]

**Normal**
[image: Normal Page Load]

While the "huge" page was loaded, i did a mysql php request on cli with some time measurements:

```
Connection took 9.9890232086182 ms
Query took 3.3938884735107 ms
```

So that is not blocking.

Any ideas on how to solve that?

Setup:

- php-fpm7.2
- nginx
- symfony3.4

Comment: I would suggest to try to use [XDebug profiler](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) to get more detailed picture about request internals

Comment: The within the Firewall the Contextlistener is that that blocks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is been blocked by the PHP Session.

You can't serve to pages that requires access to the same session id.

Although once you close/serve/release the session on the slow page, another page can be served on the same session. On the slow page just call [`Session::save()`](http://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.html#method_save) as soon as possible on your controller. This will release the session. Take into consideration that everything you do after saving the session will not be stored in the session.

Comment: Thanks!
So when a page that requires a session is loaded, a another page (thats not require a session) could not be loaded at the same time if its the same sessionId

Comment: All Symfony URL inside a firewall requires the session in order to load the token/user and validate that this token/user it is allowed to access to the current firewall. There is cases that this does not apply but it is not the usual case.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the firewall takes so long is that of **debug is enabled**.

In debug, the listeners are all wrapped with debugging listeners. **All the information in the Firewall is being profiled and logged**.

Try to run the same request with Symfony debug disabled.

Comment: Can you explain why this should be the case?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem. When sending a couple of consecutive requests to the server in a short period, the server became very slow. I enabled the profiler bar, and a lot of time was spent by the ContextListener
[image: screenshot of the profiler information]

The problem was that file server access on our server is very slow, and session information was stored on the file system, as is the default for symfony.

I configured my app to use the [PdoSessionHandler](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/pdo_session_storage.html), and the problem was gone.